# Can't remove woocommerce sidebar

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sidebar

I am using this below code to remove woocommerce sidebar, from cart and single-product page.

```
function urun_sidebar_kaldir() {
    if ( is_product() || is_cart() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'urun_sidebar_kaldir' );
```

It works in single-product page, but it doesn't work cart page.

I can't remove sidebar in cart page.

**//Update**

I am not using **woocommerce.php** in theme main folder.

And i have this templates in my theme.

```
wp-content/themes/{current-theme}/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
```

I created custom teplate for cart. And i removed **get_sidebar();** but sidebar is still displaying in cart page.

```
wp-content/themes/{current-theme}/page-cart.php
wp-content/themes/{current-theme}/page-checkout.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, most themes have multiple page templates you can choose from.

Please check:

1. go to cart page (in wp-admin).
2. See side metabox 'Page Attributes'.
3. There you can set the page template, does it have something like 'full_width'?

You can also try a different hook, like `wp_head`.

Example:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'urun_sidebar_kaldir' );
```

Let me know.

---

After checking the WOO cart template, i can't find a `do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' )`.
It does exist in the singe-product.php template.

Are you certain the cart sidebar is generated by WooCommerce?

---

Add a full-width template to your theme:

Read [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/).

Then follow the steps i mentiod at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: I am developing a new theme. And i tried 'wp_head' and 'init'

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: It not generated by Woocommerce. I tried remove get_sidebar() from page.php it removed from cart page too. But i wonder, why 'remove_action' working for single-product and not working for cart page.

Comment: Like i said: `do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' )` does exist in the `singe-product.php` template. that's why your `remove_action()` is working for single products. If the cart sidebar is not generated by WOO, you'll have to find who/what is creating it.

Comment: Well that's kinda hard without knowing how you setup everything. Do you override the Woo cart template inside your theme? Does your theme default has a sidebar? Can't you create a no-sidebar template inside your theme?

Comment: It created by wordrpress default. And located in page.php. If i remove get_sidebar in page.php it is removing in cart page too. So i created page-cart.php for special editing. But changes are not applying to cart page.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok it will work i know. But can you explain me why page-cart.php method not work? (Edited my question)

Comment: After creating the page-cart.php template, did you go to the cart page and select that template @ Page Attributes? Without that last step it won't work. Also, in your default theme template you can do a `if(! is_cart())` before you load the sidebar. Make sure that you check if WOO is active before you call Woo specific functions. That way you don't need a special page-cart.php template.

Comment: Ok i will use woocommerce conditional tags. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with the following code, but I'm not sure if this is really viable and future proof.

```
function woo_remove_sidebar() {              
    if( ! is_product() or
        ! is_cart() or
        ! is_checkout() or
        ! is_account_page() )
    {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'woo_remove_sidebar' );
```